# stop thread with udp server

Tags: java, multithreading

I've got an UDP server class which implements `Runnable` interface. I start it in the thread.
The problem is that I can't stop it. Even in Debug it stops on `pt.join()` method.

Here is my server class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.SocketException;


public class Network implements Runnable {
final int port = 6789;

DatagramSocket socket;

byte[] input = new byte[1024];
byte[] output = new byte[1024];

public Network() throws SocketException{
    socket = new DatagramSocket(6789);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true){
        DatagramPacket pack = new DatagramPacket(input,input.length);
        try {
            socket.receive(pack);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        input = pack.getData();
        System.out.println(new String(input));
        output = "Server answer".getBytes();
        DatagramPacket sendpack = new DatagramPacket(output,output.length,pack.getAddress(),pack.getPort());
        try {
            socket.send(sendpack);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is the main class

```
public class Main {

static Network network = null;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    network = new Network();
    System.out.println("Try to start server");
    Thread pt = new Thread(network);
    pt.start();

    pt.interrupt();
    try {
        pt.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Stop server");
}
}
```

**How to stop server?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

java.net reads are non-interruptible. You would have to either close the `DatagramSocket` or have it read with a timeout (`setSoTimeout()`), and when you get the resulting `SocketTimeoutException` check the interrupt status: if set, exit the thread.

Comment: +1 If you close the socket during a receive you should get an `IOException`.

Comment: @Gray Correct, in fact it is a `java.net.SocketException: socket closed`.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `interrupt` doesn't actually stop the thread, it just sets a flag.

Inside your loop, check for `isInterrupted()`.  e.g., a quick and dirty way would be change

```
while(true) 
to 
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
```

But you should consult some more documentation if you get more serious about this project.

As mentioned by @EJP, if you are hanging in the Socket IO, you'll need to close the Socket or have a timeout.

Comment: ..or send a local stack UDP message to unblock it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what EJP said, you probably should have a local boolean called running (or whatever), and set it to true before you enter your while loop. Have your while loop be conditioned on this local boolean. And provide methods (stopServer() and isRunning()) to set and check the status of the boolean. You also might want to remove the try-catch from inside the while loop and put the entire while loop within a try-catch-finally and in the finally statement perform clean-up (set running=false; close the connection, etc)

Comment: While this works, I prefer `isInterrupted()` cause it covers a few more cases, works with Executors, etc...